# nginx server configuration : rewrite to local folder

Tags: nginx

I am curently configuring a nginx server with subdomains.

I am using noip.com for DNS service, which provide me a web adress similar to 
mydomain.ddns.net

As I have subdomains, I want to access them by the adress http://mydomain.ddns.net/subdomain

In the server, the subdomain files are located here :
/var/www/mydomain.ddns.net/www/subdomain

My question is : what is the code to write in the mydomain.ddns.net nginx configuration file to redirect http://mydomain.ddns.net/subdomain to /var/www/mydomain.ddns.net/www/subdomain/welcome.php ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Quentin C

Comment: What do you mean by _subdomains_? It looks like you're talking about subdirectories. A subdomain would be: `foo.mydomain.ddns.net`, where the _root_ domain is `ddns.net`.

Comment: I want to host several websites using only on DynDns adress. Each website would be located in the folder /var/www/mydomain.ddns.net/www/.

Comment: Ok, but if the websites' URLs are `http://mydomain.ddns.net/foobar`, than they're just sub-resources of the same website.

Comment: Yes..maybe.. Is it a problem ? Sorry, i am a beginner in servers.. You are saying that the only way to have several websites hosted by the same URL is to use subdomains i.e. foo.mydomain.ddns.net adresses ? I can't do that since I am using the noip.com dyndns service.. no?

Comment: Yes, you can have different _applications_ in different folders. It's just an odd choice and wanted to make sure I understood what you were asking.

Comment: You say its an odd way to do that, but how would you have done this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of serving PHP with nginx, and I can't try this right now, but at least the configuration below should get you started.

Try to follow [this guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) to tweak it, while [this](http://www.nginxsearch.com/) should make searching the configuration docs a bit less painful.

```
user nginx nginx;

worker_processes 3;
worker_rlimit_nofile 2048;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  accept_mutex on;
  use epoll; # for Linux
}

http {
  server_tokens off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

  sendfile on;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.ddns.net;

    # To enable https
    #
    # listen 443 ssl;
    # ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/sslfiles/certificate_chain.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslfiles/certificate_key_no_passphrase.key;
    # ssl_session_cache shared:a_cache_name:1m;
    # ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    root /var/www/mydomain.ddns.net/www;

    location / {
      return 403; # forbidden
    }


    location @php_app {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?(\.php)?)(\/.*)?$;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /subdomain_one/ {
      try_files $uri/index.html @php_app;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While restarting nginx, I obtained an error : pattern "^(.+?(\.php)?)(\/.*)?$" must have 2 captures in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.ddns.net